# difficult to get info related to geoposition from server through wms in high density mobile

Tags: android, maps, openstreetmap, osmdroid, wms

I'm trying to develop an android app and I'm using osmdroid. I have a map with some points marked and when I click on one point I need to retrieve info related to it throught wms to the server. 
The thing is it works fine in a tablet that have a couple of years but if i try to click on some point displaying the app in my mobile (Samsung Galaxy S4 with xxxhdpi) is long too hard to get some info, it seems it's too difficult to click in the exact point. 
I think the difference it's due to the high density of the mobile screen.
Don't know what can I do, any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution and it's within the standards of the WMS call.

There is a parameter called "buffer" that sets like a radius around the clicked point.

Moreover it seems to work faster in the answer than before :-)

For more info about that parameter and some others: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html?highlight=getfeatureinfo#buffer